# Portable Ruby for Node in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, node.js

Because I'm using quite a few different PC's for development, I'm used to having my projects, including server binaries on a USB stick.
Node seems to be working just fine.

However, I can't use the grunt-contrib-sass module without installing Ruby.

Is there a way I can make the sass module use he Yellowsoft Portable Ruby, without adding the location to the Windows PATH ?

Comment: I'm thinking there must be a solution, with using a batch file. https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/setlocal.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.
When I run the following batch file, the Ruby binaries are available in the PATH envoirement variable.

I believe this will come in handy for users who doesn't have administrator rights on the system.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET RubyPath=C:\www\Ruby200-x64\bin

SET PATH=%PATH%;%RubyPath%

cmd.exe /k
```